# Google Sheets data validation dropdown filter based on criteria

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I have a sheet with the Training Participants and the Trainers. Trainers have to be retrained every year and their training date, the corresponding fiscal year (FY), and specialty-trained (IRT) is noted on the Trainers tab. On the Training Participant tab, the training participant records are added. To ensure that only eligible trainers are facilitating training, I am trying to add a data validation dropdown that only lists the trainers trained for the FY of the training date (Col E of the Training Participants sheet) and, if the training type is IRT, only trainers that are trained for that FY AND marked as TRUE for IRT (Col E) on the Training page.

For example, if I was entering training participants for an IST training that occurred 5/15/22, Amy Peterson, Stan Roberts, and Josh Smith would populate in the dropdown as they are eligible trainers for FY 21/22.

If I was entering training participants for an IRT training done on 7/1/22 only Amy Peterson and Gabe Winters would populate in the dropdown as those are the only two IRT trainers eligible for FY 22/23.

I know it would be easier to create a new sheet or tab for every fiscal year, but I would like to keep all of the records for each FY in these two sheets for easy reference.

Training Participants Sheet:
[image]

Trainers Sheet:
[image]

Here is my practice sheet which includes a small sample of the data I am working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rORXj5Ifgqn2RWD7GgsEy_QrUcjnz1Zd9jiUlEHxaEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Is your end goal to implement the validation in column G from `Training Participants` so that whenever you select the training type in F you get to choose a trainer from the list  in G that will be populated based in the criteria you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @FernandoLara the end goal is that the dropdown list in G filter based on training type in F and the Fiscal year (only populate trainers that are eligible for the FY the training record is for col H on the training participants sheet)

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for the recommendations. Anytime I have done tables or screenshots only, I end up getting multiple requests for a copy of the spreadsheet and typically won't get any answers or recommendations until I provide a copy of the sheet. I will edit my post to include screenshots.

Comment: Are you willing to use a script that can accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, I would be willing to use a script.